# Secure net.core api without a authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I´m need to create a web api with net.core for a mobile (Ionic) app. 
Part of this app, do not need be authenticated to see a list of products.

My problem is:

I need to create a web api, to list this products but, the user do not need to login on app, but I´d like that my application could consume this api and not be open to all (just my app can consume).

It is possible? If yes, what I need to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way you can do make the API available to your application without exposing it to the world sans auth, is to keep it internal, i.e. on the same LAN as your website and behind a firewall. This is generally the preferred approach, anyways, if it's not for public consumption as if it's public at all, there's always some potential for breach, whether authentication is required or not.

The one downside to this approach, though, is that you cannot utilize then for any external communication - things like AJAX or in your scenario a mobile application. As a result, if you need to be able to access it via mobile apps, you cannot implement it this way, which then means you *must* implement an authentication layer to protect it. There is no other alternative.

You can also do a kind of hybrid approach, as well. If there's certain API endpoints that should never be accessed publicly, you can split your API app up into external and internal portions and then keep the internal stuff internal, only exposing the APIs that are absolutely necessary for mobile app functionality. Again, though, for anything that is public, you'll need to implement an authentication layer or it will be wide open.

That said, the authentication doesn't have to be *end-user* authentication. You just need to authorize your mobile application as a client. Typically, you'd do that via client secret auth, where the application is given a client id and a secret. The client submits that to an auth endpoint and gets back a token. That token is then passed in the `Authorization` header for requests that require it. All that remains seamless to your end-user, requiring no actual physical login on their part.